# How can I include my own version of ImageMagick in my lambda zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

With AWS [disabling certain coders of ImageMagick](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3804), my lambda function which was running flawlessly for nearly 9 months, suddenly stopped working.

Some people have pointed out to me that I can still include my own version of ImageMagick in my zip file to get things to work again. How do I do this?

At the moment, I use the lambda console to upload my zip file - I have no deployment scripts. [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) AWS guide for using native module talks about using EC2 but I am put off the by the complexity of this method and the cost of running an EC2 instance.

Lastly, if I were to include my own version of ImageMagick, how would I reference it in my lambda script? Currently, I call `gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true})`

Comment: Wouldn't you just put it inside `node_modules/` [in your zip file?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)  I deploy my Lambda with a zip in the console, and that's where my dependencies are, though I haven't put IM in there.  Still learning Lambda.

Comment: You would have to do something like the tutorial you linked. You might be put off by the complexity but that is the process you would have to follow. I'm not sure why you are are put off by the EC2 cost though. You would only need a t2.nano instance for an hour or two, which would cost pennies.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's more complicated than that. It's a binary module that has to be compiled on the same underlying OS as Lambda (Amazon Linux) and statically linked.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkB.  I wrongly assumed that the suspicious functionality had been disabled in the JS wrapper, rather than in the binaries.  In hindsight, that seems unlikely.  Of course, the AMIs that back Lambda instances are [known](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) so I wouldn't expect this to be an impossible task.